# A Growth Inequality on $\mathbb{C}$-Polynomials

Tags: complex-analysis, inequality

For which class of polynomials over $\mathbb{C}^{n}$ does the following growth inequality hold? For any multi-index $\alpha$, there are positive constants $A, B, C, D < \infty$ such that
\begin{align}
|\partial^{\alpha} f | \leqslant A |\partial f|^{2} + B |f | + C |z|^{2} + D
\end{align}
holds for sufficiently large $|z|$, where $| \cdot |$ denotes the standard Euclidean norm. It seems that polynomials which violate this inequality do not vanish at the origin and have non-isolated critical points there. Does the inequality hold for polynomials which vanish at the origin and have an isolated critical point there?

Comment: Pointwise inequality? Of course not. Take  $\alpha = (2,0)$ and consider $f(z)=Mz^2$  at the origin. The inequality is $|2M| \le D$, which is pretty hard to satisfy for all $M$.

Comment: Thanks, 5pm. Your example illustrates a condition that is necessary (and one that I forgot to include). I need only the inequality to hold for $|z|>0$.

Comment: That does not help. Since both sides of the inequality are continuous in $z$, if it were true for all $z\ne 0$, it would also be true for $z=0$.

Comment: You should define "large": for all $z$ such that $|z|\ge M$, where $M$ depends on ? And please do this by editing your question, so that other readers will not have to read a chain of comments to find what the question actually is.

Comment: For $n>1$ the answer to the edited question is no, no matter how we interpret "large".  Take $f(z)=Mz_1^2 z_2^3$, and $\alpha=(2,0)$ as before. At the points where $z_1=0$, the stated inequality becomes $|2Mz_2^3|\le  C|z_2|^2 +D  $ which is false.

Comment: Is this $\mathbb{C}^n$ or $\mathbb{C}$? For the first case, a trivial counterexample is $f(x,y) = (x-y)^2 x^3, \alpha = (0,2)$. Along the direction $x = y$, $|\partial^{\alpha} f|$ grows like $2|x|^3$ but $|\partial f| = |f| = 0$...

Answer (score 1):

Of course, there is nothing special about the origin: we can shift the variables so that the origin is not a critical point at all, or is an isolated critical point. The former is achieved with $f(z)=M (z_1+1)^2 (z_2+1)^3$, the latter with $f(z)=M (z_1+1)^2 (z_2+1)^3-M(2z_1+3z_2)$. In both cases, the stated inequality fails for $\alpha=(2,0)$ when $z_1=-1$ and $|z_2|$ is large.

*Edit*: if you want $f$ to vanish at the origin (in addition to having an isolated critical point there, take 
$$f(z)=M (z_1+1)^2 (z_2+1)^3-M(1+2z_1+3z_2)$$

I think you should focus on why any such inequality should be true (and what you need it for), instead of trying to escape known counterexamples with minor modifications.

Comment: Thank you +1. However, I disagree with your remark about the origin. I believe it to be a key component with this growth inequality. Polynomials which vanish at the origin and have isolated critical points there seem to satisfy it.

Comment: @user02138 I just gave a counterexample to that.

Comment: Again, thank you, this is very helpful!